# Partially transparent background image

Tags: html, css, background, transparency, transparent

I have a question, since I couldn't find any solution yet.

So I have this image, which is fully transparent in the "center" and partially on the border as you can see. What I'd like to achieve is, the "border" should be transparent and the "center" should be red.But the border should be fully transparent. So in this case, white.

I'm not sure if is this even possible with CSS or HTML, the reason why I need to do this in CSS or HTML because I'm looping through the database, and every displayed record would have a different background color, but the "border" should remain transparent. So creating the whole image in 10 colors or more is not an option for me, because then the site might would be too heavy.

Thank you very much guys,
Mark

EDIT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL4K1.png
So to be more precise, I've created another image, what I want to achieve.
At the start I got the 2 images on the left side, the first one on the top is fully transparent in the middle, and has ~50% opacity on the border as you can see, so partially transparent. The second one is just an image, but the second image is always changing, like a slideshow.

The other image to the right would be the final result, I've set a gray background to be more visible. So what I have in my mind, is that possible? What I want to achieve is to cut the slideshow images border like this. But I don't want to photoshop every image which is in the slideshow, so I was thinking, maybe I can achieve something similar like this with CSS. I'm thinking in some z-index, or something. But thats not working, because I get an image like what I've linked on the top.

This is all I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxZrL.png
My problem here is, I can see the image on the partially transparent border, I'd like to get something similar what is on the first image on the right (without the blue things of course, I couldn't cut it, I'm not a designer :P )

Comment: So you mean like you want to use your image as a mask?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use it as a mask, but still has the background, I've explained in the EDIT part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but take a lok at this link : http://css-tricks.com/transparency-in-web-design/
You might have to take a look at the PNG file format you're using.

Comment: the linked image is a div, with a background image and background color, the background image is fully transparent in the middle, and partially transparent on the border as you can see on the linked image above in my post. The PNG format is good, I'd like have the red color in the middle, without the light red color on the border. But I guess it's not possible to set the image to be transparent where fully the image fully transparent and ignore the transparency where partially transparent. This should be my question, maybe I've asked wrong. Sorry about my English. :)

Comment: In the link i sent you there are a few examples on how to use css to give colors transparency as quoted from the link: "Using RGBa for a color value in CSS, you can set a transparency level on any color. This has the distinct advantage over opacity in that it doesn't have any affect on descendants. It is also nice in that creating faded out variations of a color is as easy as changing the final alpha value. Speaking of color variations, that is even easier to do with HSLa, and is still able to handle transparency.

#anything {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  /* 50% transparent */
}"

Comment: It seems it will affect HTML elements, but i'm not sure it will do the trick with images embedded in HTML. Try it out and report back please, i'm curious too now :)

Comment: I know what you tried to do here, but maybe I'm not precise enough, or my english might be poor to describe what my problem is. So I'll try to describe is in another way. I have an image, z-index: 1, this is a picture about a hot girl. :) I have another image, z-index: 2, this is the transparent image, which is fully transparent in the center, but partially transparent on the border. I'll create another image, so I can explain it more simple. Just a few minutes. :)

Comment: It seems you want to use image in z-index 2 as a frame right? There could be some tricks to bypass the trouble you're in :). And yes, i would now like to see the pic with the hot girl please :)

Comment: Probably it would be best to actually post a link with a small example of what you want to do, that way i could be of more assistance.

Comment: Okay, sorry CJ, I was afk at the weekend. If you are still here, I can create a sample, what I want to do. :)

Comment: Hi custy, just publish or send html, css and images with what you did and what you're supposed to do. Try to keep it as simple as possible and i'll try to give you a hand.

Comment: Hi CJ, i've edited the original post, so you can check if you're still intrested. :)

Comment: Well, since you keep on sending static images and not the actual html / css files, i found you a site that might just be the answer you're  looking for : http://www.magicedit.com/MaskinganImagewithaT.cl and the working demos: http://template.magicedit.com/ht_imageMask/ . Hope it helps  :)

Comment: Many thanks, CJ! It works now! This is what I wanted, but I wasn't sure I can do this in html/javascript/css. Thanks again!!